# How can Twisted call Qt back?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, twisted

I am practicing PyQt+Twisted by writing a chat client. This requires getting the two event loops to play nice. I want to figure out how to do this without the Twisted QTReactor. The pattern I'm trying to achieve is

1. Qt runs normally, Twisted runs in another thread (say a QThread).
2. Qt functions/methods call Twisted functions with `callFromThread`.
3. We hook up the deferreds given to us by Twisted so that they cause emission of Qt signals. In this way the Twisted thread can call back the Qt thread.

I've actually gotten that part working. The heart of the solution is this function

```
def callFromMain(self, func, successSignal, *args):
    """Call an async I/O function with a Qt signal as it's callback

    func is the Twisted function you want to invoke. It probably returns a
    deferred. successSignal is the signal you want to emit once the asynchronous
    call finishes. This signal will be emitted with the result of func as an
    argument
    """

    def succeed(result):
        self.emit(successSignal, result)

    def wrapped():
        d = defer.maybeDeferred(func, *args)
        if successSignal is not None:
            d.addCallback(succeed)

    reactor.callFromThread(wrapped)
```

The problem is that I don't know what to do when I get "un-asked-for" data. For example, someone *else* might send out a chat message. I need to be able to detect the receipt of the data in the Twisted thread and somehow get that data into the Qt thread. This seems tricky because in this case I haven't provided the Twisted part of the program with a signal to use as a callback. How can I do that?

Below please find complete example code to run my almost working chat client and server. To use these programs first copy the server and client as .py files and the ui specification as a .ui file. Run the server and then run the client. Once the client window is up, click the "connect" button. You should see a message on the server indicating a new connection. Then try typing into the line edit and clicking the "send" button. You'll see that the data makes it to the server and back, but that it doesn't show up in the client's QTextEdit box. This is because **I can't figure out how to get the data from the ChatProtocol to the Qt part of the program.** How can we do this?

**SERVER (asyncore)**

```
import asyncore
import socket
import constants as C

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 12344

class ChatServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    """Receive and forward chat messages

    When a new connection is made we spawn a dispatcher for that
    connection.
    """
    ADDRESS_FAMILY = socket.AF_INET
    SOCKET_TYPE = socket.SOCK_STREAM
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.map = {}
        self.address = (host,port)
        self.clients = []
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, map=self.map)

    def serve(self):
        """Bind to socket and start asynchronous loop"""
        self.create_socket(self.ADDRESS_FAMILY, self.SOCKET_TYPE)
        self.bind(self.address)
        print("ChatServer bound to %s %s"%self.address)
        self.listen(1)
        asyncore.loop(map=self.map)

    def writable(self):
        return False

    def readable(self):
        return True

    def newMessage(self, data, fromWho):
        """Put data in all clients' buffers"""
        print("new data: %s"%data)
        for client in self.clients:
            client.buffer = client.buffer + data

    def handle_accept(self):
        """Deal with newly accepted connection"""
        (connSock, clientAddress) = self.accept()
        print("New connection accepted from %s %s"%clientAddress)
        self.clients.append(ChatHandler(connSock, self.map, self))

class ChatHandler(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, sock, map, server):
        self.server = server
        self.buffer = ''
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, sock, map)

    def writable(self):
        return len(self.buffer) > 0

    def readable(self):
        return True

    def handle_read(self):
        """Notify server of any new incoming data"""
        data = self.recv(4096)
        if data:
            self.server.newMessage(data, self)

    def handle_write(self):
        """send some amount of buffer"""
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]

if __name__=='__main__':
    if HOST is None:
        HOST = raw_input('Host: ')
    if PORT is None:
        PORT = int(raw_input('Port: '))
    s = ChatServer(HOST, PORT)
    s.serve()
```

**CLIENT (PyQt + Twisted)**

```
import sys

import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui
import PyQt4.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt4.uic as uic

import twisted.internet.reactor as reactor
import twisted.internet.defer as defer
import twisted.internet.protocol as protocol

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('ui.ui')
        self.networkThread = NetworkThread()
        self.networkThread.start()

        self.ui.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.sendMessage)
        self.ui.connectButton.clicked.connect(self.getNetworkConnection)
        #Make connections from network thread signals to our slots
        self.connect(self.networkThread,
                     self.networkThread.sigConnected,
                     self.onConnected)
        self.connect(self.networkThread,
                     self.networkThread.sigNewData,
                     self.onNewData)
        self.ui.show()

    def getNetworkConnection(self):
        factory = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, ChatProtocol)
        self.networkThread.callFromMain(factory.connectTCP,
                                        self.networkThread.sigConnected,
                                        'localhost', 12344)

    def onConnected(self, p):
        print("Got a protocol!")
        self.cxn = p

    def onNewData(self, data):
        self.ui.outputBox.append('\r\n'+data)

    def sendMessage(self):
        message = str(self.ui.inputBox.text())
        self.networkThread.callFromMain(self.cxn.send, None, message)

class NetworkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    """Run the twisted reactor in its own thread"""
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.sigConnected = QtCore.SIGNAL("sigConnected")
        self.sigNewData = QtCore.SIGNAL("sigNewData")

    def run(self):
        reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=0)

    def callFromMain(self, func, successSignal, *args):
        """Call an async I/O function with a Qt signal as it's callback"""

        def succeed(result):
            self.emit(successSignal, result)

        def wrapped():
            d = defer.maybeDeferred(func, *args)
            if successSignal is not None:
                d.addCallback(succeed)

        reactor.callFromThread(wrapped)

class ChatProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print("Got data: %s"%data)
        print("...but I don't know how to pass it to Qt :(")

    def send(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class ChatFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = ChatProtocol

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UI file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QTextEdit" name="outputBox"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="inputBox"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="sendButton">
          <property name="text">
           <string>send</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>40</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="connectButton">
          <property name="text">
           <string>connect</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: The reason that the reactor is pluggable, and we have reactors that specifically support GUI libraries, is specifically so application programmers (like you) don't have to jump through these hoops :).  Use `qt4reactor` and your problems will probably just go away.

Comment: In the case that I make a Twisted call and want to act on a response everything is easy. I can use the pyqt4reactor and the usual Twisted callback system, or I can use my `callFromMain` function. In these cases a QObject is in charge and can emit signals as needed during the callback phase. The problem happens when I get un-asked-for data, like a chat message. In that case my protocol does dataReceived and I need to somehow emit a Qt signal at that time. It's not obvious how to do that. I can just give the protocol a QObject as an attribute to use for emitting signals. Good idea?